# IBM MQ v9 - Managed File Transfer - Initiate MFT once file is placed in folder

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

How can I initiate a file transfer, once a file is placed in a folder, using IBM MQ v9.0 Managed File Transfer. I can achieve the same by below transfer initiation methods (have tried and tested, working fine).

- Transfer by a initiation file
- Transfer by a schedule
- Transfer by a monitor

A file monitor is fine, but the trigger file contains the details of files to be transferred. When the trigger file is placed in the folder, files specified in the trigger file are being transferred.

I need a solution, once a file is placed in the folder, the file itself should be fetched and transferred.

As per below IBM link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/create_monitor_cmd.htm in the purpose section

> "For example, you can use a resource monitor in the following way: An
>   external application puts one or more files in a known directory and
>   when processing is complete, the external application places a trigger
>   file in a monitored directory. The trigger file is then detected and a
>   defined file transfer starts, which copies the files from the known
>   directory to a destination agent".

i.e We have to place the set of files to be transferred and then place a (second) trigger file to initiate the transfer. My question is, is there a way to initiate without the second file, once a file is placed in the transfer directory.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Regards

Yasothar

Comment: Using the monitor you are able trigger a transfer that transfers the files mentioned in the trigger file. Can you please explain what you mean by "once a file is placed in the folder, the file itself should be fetched and transferred."?

Comment: Once I place a file a.txt in a folder it should be fetched and transferred. In a monitor a file containing the details of the files to be transferred are placed in a trigger folder and once placed, the trigger event happens and the files mentioned in the trigger file are being transferred.

Comment: The issue is I don't know the file name that is going to be placed in the polling folder and the trigger file should be placed to the trigger folder to initiate the event. My requirement is the file transfer event should happen once the a.txt is placed in a specific folder.

Comment: Can't you simply configure a monitor to poll for a specific pattern of the trigger file for triggering?